# Default for ADTF filter trigger

Tags: c++, adtf, adtf3

In ADTF 3.0 triggers are separated from filters.

- Is there a default trigger or must I define a trigger for every filter?

If there is a default trigger

- Is it data or time triggered?
- Is it possible to define my own default trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default triggers within ADTF3 depends on the used filter template:

The Default Trigger for a

```
template<typename TriggerFunctionImpl, tTimeStamp DEFAULT_PERIOD > 
class time_triggered_filter 
{ //... };
```

is a time trigger (A trigger function that is called periodically)

The Default Trigger for a

```
template<typename TriggerFunctionImpl, typename InPinListOfTriggers>
class data_triggered_filter 
{ //... };
```

is a data trigger (A trigger function that is called if data was received on one of the given pins within

```
InPinListOfTriggers
```